# Timestamp generator register location on Cortex-M4 (PSELCTRL CNTCR)

Tags: arm, debugging, time, cortex-m, cortex-m4

I am trying to find the location of the register where the timestamp generator can be enabled on a Cortex-M4 processor.

In the [CoreSight SoC Technical Reference Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0480/d/DDI0480D_coresight_soc_r2p1_trm.pdf) on page 3-210 it is mentioned that the register (CNTCR) is in the PSELCTRL region (see image). However, I am not able to find the base memory address of this PSELCTRL region.

[image: extrait from CoreSight manual]

Can I find this address somewhere in the ROM table that indicates the implemented debug components? But then how do I know which ID it is?

Or is it defined in some datasheet?

Comment: 0xE0000FD0 -
0xE0000FFC - - - Optional CoreSight management and ID registers. See Appendix D1
ARMv7-M CoreSight Infrastructure IDs for more information.

Comment: searched for coresight in the arm docs